# What does the phrase "bounce the moon" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the phrase "bounce the moon" as found in [this song](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/f/frank+sinatra/you+make+me+feel+so+young_20056114.html)
mean?

Comment: It's quite literal.  Have you ever bounced a ball?  He's saying he'd like to bounce the moon just like a big balloon.

Answer (score 1):

"Bounce the moon" is not an idiom. It could fall under *hyperbole*, because it is impossible to bounce the moon.

The next line is "Just like a big toy balloon". This is under simile, as he wants to bounce the moon *like* a big toy balloon.